# Why are beers called "lagartos" in Cuba?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, comida, animales, cuba

Why is a beer known as a *lagarto* ("lizard") in Cuba?

> **lagarto:** (uso vulgar) cerveza (*Cuba*).
>
> - [*Glosario popular cubano* (Estudio de cubanismos actuales)](https://ruc.udc.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/2183/8201/LYT_20_2003_art_12.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Neither the [DLE entry](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MnrWCnQ) (6.) nor the [Diccionario de Americanismos one](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=lagarto) (V. 1.) explain the etymology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another older word for beer in Cuba is [*láguer*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=l%C3%A1guer)<sup>1</sup>. *Lagarto* came to be used as a synonym solely due to its phonetic similarity to *laguér*; the word has nothing to do with lizards in this context:

> La motivación puede ser a veces puramente fónica, sin que medie ninguna relación semántica entre la palabra sustituida y la sustituidora. En el ejemplo presentado podría también considerarse que entra en acción un procedimiento de derivación mixta (véase a este respecto § 3.4.4):
>
> > **lagarto** [*ampl. de* **láguer**] *m. cul. vulg. gen.* cerveza [*sin. véase en* **fría**]
>
> - [*Variación lingüística en el español de Cuba*](https://is.cuni.cz/webapps/zzp/download/120095587), Ariel Laurencio Tacoronte
>   <sub>3. MORFOLOGÍA Y SINTAXIS: 3.4 Cambios del significante: 3.4.3 Sustitución</sub>

---

<sup>**1.** Though *láguer* clearly derives from the English *lager*/German *Lagerbier*, in Cuban Spanish this refers to any type of beer, not just lagers.</sup>